# Ошибка при попытке вызова метода, который получает данные из бд sqlite3

Tags: python, sqlite

На Python пишу скрипт, который будет выводить запросы пользователей. Для работы с sqlite3 написал класс, в котором есть метод get_user_queries.

```
def get_user_queries(self, user_id):
    with self.connection:
        result = self.cursor.execute('SELECT query FROM user_query WHERE user_id = ?', (user_id,))
        queries = result.fetchall()
        return queries
```

При вызове этого метода

```
queries = db.get_user_queries(user_id)
```

возникает ошибка:

> sqlite3.ProgrammingError: SQLite objects created in a thread can only
>   be used in that same thread.The object was created in thread id 13900
>   and this is thread id 16660.

В чем причина и как можно решить проблему?

Comment: Причина в том, что и написано — обращаетесь к БД не из того потока. Можно подробнее узнать, что у вас за потоки и зачем они вам?

Comment: @andreymal Я уже разобрался, спасибо. Эта ошибка возникала из-за того, что пользовался не тем соединением с базой данных. Добавил в контекст queries открытие соединения с базой данных - все заработало.

Answer (score 3):

Нужно включить поддержку нескольких потоков для SQLite3 добавив следующие аргументы для соединения с БД

```
sqlite.connect(":memory:", check_same_thread = False)
```

Answer (score 0):

[**chopchopa:**](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/533876/%d0%9e%d1%88%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bf%d1%8b%d1%82%d0%ba%d0%b5-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0-%d0%bc%d0%b5%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b0-%d0%ba%d0%be%d1%82%d0%be%d1%80%d1%8b%d0%b9-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%83%d1%87%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82-%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b5-%d0%b8%d0%b7-%d0%b1%d0%b4-sqlite3#comment668467_533876) Эта ошибка возникала из-за того, что пользовался не тем соединением с базой данных. Добавил в контекст queries открытие соединения с базой данных - все заработало.

Answer (score 0):

В файле config.py к имени базы данных добавить ?check_same_thread=False

Например:

```
import os
basedir = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))

class Config(object):
    SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI = os.environ.get('DATABASE_URL') or \
                              'sqlite:///' + os.path.join(basedir, 'app.db?check_same_thread=False')
```